# percent complete / work complete in ms project

Tags: project-server, ms-project

I'm new in MS project

I want to know what's the difference between percent complete / work complete ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Microsoft Project and Project server, there are two fields `% complete` and `%work complete`

Both fields refer to the percent of achievements.but the difference is

- **%Complete** field value calculated based on **Duration**.

  - The equation of % complete is = `(Actual Duration / Duration) * 100`
- **%Work Complete** field value calculated based on **Work**.

  - The equation of % Work Complete is = `(Actual Work / Work) * 100`

**For example:**

You have a project that has one task. this task has duration 7 days that started in 08/04/2017 and today is 11/04/2017 so the percent of achievements based on duration (%Complete) is about 50 % if your plan is **on schedule** and based on the actual duration.

Meanwhile, the `% Work Complete` will depend on actual resources work based on their timesheet and working hour per day for this task.

For more details check

- [Understanding Project's Percent Complete vs. Percent Work Complete](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-projects-percent-complete-vs-percent-work-complete/)
- [HOW TO CALCULATE %COMPLETE VS %WORK COMPLETE IN MICROSOFT PROJECT.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/10/25/complete-vs-work-complete-in-microsoft-project-how-calculated/)

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, i'm muddled between the actual duration and duration definition ?

Comment: to avoid any type of confusion please check Duration fields at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Duration-fields-2db59ee9-cc7e-425e-a6e8-652833401c01 please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification also, please mark my answer if it helped you :)